# Center ul between floats in container

Tags: html, css

I want to center a `ul` between a `float left` and `float right`. They are inside a container which is with a fixed width and is also centered.

```
<header>
<div class="conatiner">
    <div class="left"><img></div>
    <div class="right"><img></idv>
    <ul class="center">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<header>
```

I want them to look like this:

```
[     [[logo]            [Item 1 Item 2 Item 3]          [options]]     ]
```

My css is something like this:

```
header {
    width: 100%;
}
.container {
     max-width: 1200px;
}
.left {
     float: left;
 }
.right {
     float: right;
 }
 .center {
      text-align: center;
 }
```

However the `.center ul` is centered between the .`left` and `.right` and because `.left` has a larger width than `.right` it gets shifted a little to the right. What I want to achieve is to make it centered no matter how big `.left` and `.right` are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can reset [BFC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context) for ul , so it can center itself in between floatting elements without laying under it.

`Diplay:table;` would be appropriate since container will also shrink on its content:

```css
header {
    width: 100%;
  background:linear-gradient(to left, gray 50%, lightgray 50%);
}
.container {
     max-width: 1200px;
}
.left {
     float: left;
  margin-right:50px;/* cause it is 50px less wide than the other one */
 }
.right {
     float: right;
 }
 .center {
      display:table;
   margin:auto;
   padding:0;
   border-spacing:0.25em;
 }
.center li {
  display:table-cell;
  border:1px solid;
  }
```

```html
<header>
<div class="container">
    <div class="left"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50"></div>
    <div class="right"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50"></div>
    <ul class="center">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<header>
```

or flex:

```css
header {
    width: 100%;
  background:linear-gradient(to left, gray 50%, lightgray 50%);/* see center */
}
.container {
     max-width: 1200px;
  display:flex;
}
.left {
    order:-1;
  margin-right:-50px;/* if know wich is biiger and how much bigger an equal negative margin of that extra size may swallow the difference .. */ 
 }
.right {
     order:1;
 }
 .center {
  display:flex;
   margin:auto;/* instead : justify-content:space-between; on parent (given into another answer ) */
   padding:0;
   order:0
 }
.center li {
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0.25em;
  border:solid 1px;
  }
```

```html
<header>
<div class="container">
    <div class="left"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50"></div>
    <div class="right"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50"></div>
    <ul class="center">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<header>
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case you can use `position: absolute` on `ul` and `transform: translateX(-50%)` to center.

With `position: absolute` you remove `ul` from elements flow so width of images doesn't affect position of `ul` and it will always stay in center of window.

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
}
.left {
  float: left;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
.center {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="conatiner">
    <div class="left"><img src="" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor."></div>
    <div class="right"><img src="" alt="right"></div>
    <ul class="center">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and easiest way is flexbox. Like this:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<header>
<div class="container">
    <div class="left"><img src="http://design.ubuntu.com/wp-content/uploads/ubuntu-logo32.png"></div>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="right"><img src="http://design.ubuntu.com/wp-content/uploads/ubuntu-logo32.png"></div>
</div>
<header>
```

Comment: Well my left and right are not the same size. The left on is bigger and it pushes .center to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```css
.inline-block { display: inline-block; }
.floatright { float: right; }
.floatcenter { margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; }
.floatleft { float: left; }
```

```html
<div style="text-align:center;">
<div class="inline-block floatleft">Logo</div>
<div class="inline-block floatcenter">Menu</div>
<div class="inline-block floatright">Options</div>
</div>
```